# Using Micron ORM Model Objects

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use model objects to make my code less vulnerable but I'm having a problem with the syntax I believe.

In the Documentation for the Micron ORM Documentation https://kimtooflex.gitbook.io/workspace/crud/find-search-records it displays the following example:

```
MicronDbContext micron = new MicronDbContext();
//gets all customers from Nairobi city
 var customers = micron.GetRecords<Customer>(
                      new Customer()
                      {
                        City = "Nairobi"
                       }
                     );

  foreach (var customer in customers)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(customer.CustomerName);
   }
```

This is what I've tried and the value keeps showing NULL. Is this a syntax error?

What i'm trying to achieve is the following sql command:

```
//IEnumerable<Places> places = micron.GetRecords<Places>("SELECT * FROM `places` WHERE `id` = '" + frmPlaceList.chid + "'");
```

This is what is not working:

```
var places = micron.GetRecords<Places>(
                     new Place()
                     {
                         id = frmPlaceList.chid
                     }
                    );
```

The error that I’m receiving is that it is giving me the wrong Id. How can I fix my code to solve this problem?

EDIT: There is a bug with the ORM in which it doesn’t output the correct value. This is currently being worked on but no fix yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I entered:

```
tabulate1.SubscribeHook("edit", (e) =>
{
    new Lib.Popup.transparentBg(this.ParentForm, new Forms.frmFournisseur(Program.db.GetRecord<Fournisseur>(1)));
    
    LoadData();
});
```

It always gives me the first recording I can not have access to other recording. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<Places> places = micron.GetRecords<Places>($"id='{ frmPlaceList.chid}'");
```

Comment: Could you give some explanation with your answer please.

Comment: It is filtering by id by passing it as a parameter